# $scope.myDataArray.map() ends with Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a function which takes array from scope, formats it in some manner depending on the options passed to it and returns a new array.

It looks like this:

```
$scope.utils.data: function (options) {
if (options === 'table') {
    return $scope.sourceData
}
else {
    return $scope.sourceData
        .map(function (group, index) {
            return {
                x: group.x || 0,
                y: group.y || 0,
                radius: group.r || 0,
                deals: group.d || 0,
                id: index,
                label: group.type
            }
        })
}
```

}

I check options to be 'table', then return the source data unmodified. But if it's something else, then return a reformatted data as an array.

This example above works fine, but now I want to add more options as a parameter, so decide to use an object, like `{type:'table', excluded:[2, 20, 31]}` so that to exclude three items if this parameter is present.

The issue is that if I turn options into an object, and check `options.type` or `options.excluded`, like I did before, but with an object, not a string, it returns me [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20safeGetter($scope);%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20safeGetter($scope);%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20safeGetter($scope);%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20safeGetter($scope);%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20safeGetter($scope);%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D%5D).

In the error documentation is written:

> One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called.

So I feel that  `return $scope.sourceData.map()` itself is not legit in this case, but it only breaks when I pass options as an object, not a string, and otherwise it works fine.

How can I workaround this issue? Any clues?